# Finding the limit of an integral (IAT)

Tags: integration, limits, functions

Consider the functions

> $g(x)$ =
>   \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if $x$ belongs to $[-1,1]$} \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}

and

> $$f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{x-h}^{x+h} g(y) \,dy}{2h}.$$

We are asked to find $f(1)$. Now I tried using L'Hospital Rule and then Leibnitz for the numerator and I got $-1/2$ but for some reason I can't completely convince myself that its not zero. Looking for some views that could tell me whether I am right about $-1/2$ and if I am, why isn't it zero?

Comment: I guess you could use L'Hospital's Rule here, but that's an overkill. The given function $g(x)$ is easy enough to be integrated directly in order to find the numerator of the fraction.

Comment: If $h>0$ then you can just replace the upper limit $x+h$ by $1$ and then you easily get the answer as $1/2$. Similarly deal with the case when $h<0$.

Comment: And why do you think the answer should be $0$?

Comment: @Paramanand sorry not 1/2 I was getting -1/2. At 1+h its zero and 1-h it would be 1, so by lebnitz theorem you would get (0-1)/2 and that's -1/2?

Comment: The right approach is the one mentioned in the answer by Salahamam_Fatima. Yo use Leibniz you need to find the anti-derivative of $ g(y) $ you are just using the values of $g$ and not its anti-derivative.

Comment: I still don't get why we need the anti-derivative. We are finding the limit of an indeterminate form. So I applied L'Hospital's Rule. the numerator would just become g(x+h)-g(x-h). the denominator would be 2. and as we are finding f(1) the numerator would be g(1+h)-g(1-h)=0-1= -1. And hence a I am getting -1/2.  Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule does not apply here because you don't know if the numerator is differentiable. Moreover even if it was differentiable the derivative would have been $g(x+h) +g(x-h) $.

Comment: In order to apply L'Hospital's Rule you need to split the integral into two, one from $1-h$ to $1$ and another $1$ to $1+h$. Then it can be shown that the whole integral is differentiable with derivative $g(1+h)+g(1-h)$ and then you can get the answer as $1/2$.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $h>0$,

$$\int_{1-h}^{1+h}g (y)dy=\int_{1-h} ^1 1dy=h $$

For $h <0$,
$$\int_{1-h}^{1+h}g (y)dy=$$
$$-\int_{1+h}^{1-h}g (y)dy=-\int_{1+h}^1 1dy=h $$

thus $f (1)=\frac {1}{2} $.

Comment: First mean value theorem is applicable only when integrand is continuous. Here $g $ is discontinuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You're right .thx.